# Using UIView's mask with multiple other views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, mask

### Description

Is there a way or workaround to use multiple `UIView`s as a combined mask for another `UIView`?

Let's say I have a background `UIImageView` where I want to cutout the shape of a `UIImageView` and a `UITextView`. Or actually only make those parts visible on the background view.

### What I've tried so far

*Examples are simplified, so views don't have frames, auto layout or what ever.*

#### Basic setup

```
let backgroundView = UIImageView()
let imageView = UIImageView()
let textView = UITextView()
```

#### 1. Can only use one view as a mask

```
// I can only use one of the other views as mask here
backgroundView.mask = imageView
```

#### 2. Can't use a "whole view hierarchy" as a mask

```
let maskView = UIView()
maskView.addSubview(imageView)
maskView.addSubview(textView)

// Doesn't work, as it seems as only the maskView is used, and it's subviews are ignored
backgroundView.mask = maskView
```

#### 3. Combine multiple view layers into one mask layer

```
let maskLayer = CALayer()
maskLayer.addSublayer(imageView.layer)
maskLayer.addSublayer(textView.layer)

// While this works, I get random crashes
backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

It seems like crashes occur when removing such views from the hierarchy again, which seems to create "Zombies":

> An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'CALayer' object (zombie) at address: 0x60000242f8c0.

> 0 libsystem_malloc.dylib malloc_zone_calloc
> 1 libsystem_malloc.dylib calloc
> 2 libobjc.A.dylib _objc_rootAllocWithZone
> 3 QuartzCore +[CALayer allocWithZone:]
> 4 UIKitCore -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
> 5 UIKitCore UIViewCommonInitWithFrame
> 6 UIKitCore -[UIView initWithFrame:]
> 7 UIKitCore -[UIScrollView initWithFrame:]
> 8 UIKitCore -[UITextView initWithFrame:textContainer:]

Unfortunately I have no clue why this happens, but I guess, it's maybe not a good idea to use `UIView.layer`s as layers/masks in other views. Or do I have to move the mask back somehow, or remove it? Maybe I'm only missing something here, and this approach should work?

#### 4. Manually render this stuff?

Have not really tried this yet, but I fear to make things too complicated, as I then would have to manually ensure updates, when stuff changes (like `imageView` or `textView` gets moved or resized, which can happen btw.)

Answer (score 0):

The only "solution" that worked for me was having a "background view" for each "cutout view" and then using the "cutout view" as mask on the "background view".

Example:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let image = UIImage(named: "some-image")
let backgroundView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let backgroundView2 = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let textView = UITextView(frame: frame)

backgroundView.image = image
backgroundView.mask = textView
backgroundView2.image = image
backgroundView2.mask = imageView
```

The "background views" and "cutout views" have the same position and size (frame) and each background view uses the same image.

Maybe that's not the most elegant solution, but it did the trick ;-)